# azure-ad-b2c - Question about B2C+MFA setup

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, multi-factor-authentication

I am an engineer from the Azure B2C support team and I have a customer with the following concern: Is it possible to use an office phone with phone extension on the MFA settings for either user flow or custom policy? Is this something we can modify? All I get is how to enable and disable it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is a special case. If your phone extension can be accessed directly with the format xxxxxxxx-xxx, you could enter it in as "xxxxxxxxxxx"  when you signing up with Azure AD B2C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently MFA with office phone (extension) is not available with User flow/Custom policy. 
As the Azure recently added the [phone sign-up and sign-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/phone-authentication) with custom policies to the public preview.
we may expect this feature in future.

You can raise [User voice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback) on this request.

For office phone with extension there is [two-factor verification method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/user-help/multi-factor-authentication-setup-office-phone) but not using User flow/Custom policy